# CD-RW burning - fast blanking vs. full blanking

Tags: compact-disc, cd-burning, cd-rw

When preparing a used CD-Rewritable disc for reuse by "blanking" it, what are the disadvantages of fast blanking as compared to full blanking?  Is there any data integrity consequence to fast blanking, such as increased probability of data errors or lower longevity as a result of not doing a full blanking?

I figure that fast blanking is similar to the quick format of a hard drive, where it clears header information and metadata but leaves the data blocks on the disk.  Wikipedia and other articles about CD-RW don't give any more specific information than "Fast blanking is much quicker, and is **usually** sufficient to allow rewriting the disc."

But they only say "usually", so what are the circumstances when fast blanking isn't sufficient to allow rewriting?  I don't care about the recoverability or lack thereof of the old data, I just want to be able to write the new data without errors or rapid deterioration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the re-burning is much more important than blanking. If you're concerned about errors, then use a slower burning speed.

As far as disk deterioration, you're going to get anywhere from 5-100 burns out of a disk. To help maximize your data retainment:

- use higher quality CDs (check the reviews)
- [store and handle with good practices](http://www.framedestination.com/CD_DVD_storage_archiving.html)
- write at slower speeds